# HttpClient.PostAsync to WCF service from Win8 app gives Error 400 Bad Request

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, windows-8

I have a Windows 8 app attempting to access a RESTful WCF service.

I also tried accessing the service with a console app with the same error.

I have a basic object i'm trying to send across to the service from my Win8 client, but i'm getting an HTTP 400 error.

**Service code**

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
public class PushClientData
{
    [DataMember(Order=0)]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order=1)]
    public string ChannelUri { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IRecruitService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "client")]
    void RegisterApp(PushClientData app);
}

public class RecruitService : IRecruitService
{
    public void RegisterApp(PushClientData app)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Client code**

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = new PushClientData
                       {
                           ClientId = "client1",
                           ChannelUri = "channel uri goes here"
                       };
        await PostToServiceAsync<PushClientData>(data, "client");
    }

    private async Task PostToServiceAsync<T>(PushClientData data, string uri)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:17641/RecruitService.svc/") };

        StringContent content;
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (T));
            ser.WriteObject(ms, data);
            ms.Position = 0;
            content = new StringContent(new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd());
        }

        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've looked at the request in fiddler and it's going out to

```
http://localhost:17641/RecruitService.svc/client
```

like i think it should, but the return is error 400 (Bad request) each time.

**Edit**

Raw request from Fiddler is below.  I added the . after localhost so Fiddler would pick it up.  I get the same error if I take it our or leave it it.

```
POST http://localhost.:17641/RecruitService.svc/clients HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml
Host: localhost.:17641
Content-Length: 159
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<PushClientData xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ClientId>client1</ClientId>
    <ChannelUri>channel uri goes here</ChannelUri>
</PushClientData>
```

Comment: Make sure your client side is correct (try it in a desktop app). Other things to try are [enabling loopback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx), and poking a hole in your firewall.

Comment: Can you include the RAW HTTP request from fiddler?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the angle braces?

Comment: Can you change the content-Type to application/xml and try

Comment: Tried with a Console app and cahngint the content type to application/xml, same error.  Also tried running the service and console client in VS 2012 on Win7 resulting in the same Bad Request error

Answer (score -1):

Hi @Michael here you missed some thing in ServiceContract

in place of

```
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "client")]
 void RegisterApp(PushClientData app);
```

replace with

```
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "client")]
 void client(PushClientData app);
```

or make it as

```
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "RegisterApp")]
 void RegisterApp(PushClientData app);
```

UriTemplate value must be same as ServiceContract method name.

Comment: This is completely false.